# Google Maps API can write to Firebase, not read

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-api-3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Maps API with Firebase using [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/firebase).

But whatever I do, I can only write to the database, not read. My rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
}
```

The API key is not restricted. 
I can clearly see the new data points in my database when clicking on the map, but no 'heatpoints' appear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "clicks": {
      ".indexOn": "timestamp"
    }    
  }
}
```